# IBMQ.load_account() fails with "403 Client Error"

Tags: programming, qiskit

I alredy save an account but when I want to laod it I get a error like this
how can I fix it ?

````
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\providers\ibmq\api\session.py in request(self, method, url, bare, **kwargs)
    273             response = super().request(method, final_url, headers=headers, **kwargs)
--> 274             response.raise_for_status()
    275         except RequestException as ex:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py in raise_for_status(self)
    940         if http_error_msg:
--> 941             raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
    942 

HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://auth.quantum-computing.ibm.com/api/version

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

RequestsApiError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-beb09c0bf764> in <module>
----> 1 IBMQ.load_account()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\providers\ibmq\ibmqfactory.py in load_account(self)
    182         # Explicitly check via a server call, to allow environment auth URLs
    183         # contain IBM Quantum Experience v2 URL (but not auth) slipping through.
--> 184         version_info = self._check_api_version(credentials)
    185 
    186         # Check the URL is a valid authentication URL.

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\providers\ibmq\ibmqfactory.py in _check_api_version(credentials)
    453         version_finder = VersionClient(credentials.base_url,
    454                                        **credentials.connection_parameters())
--> 455         return version_finder.version()
    456 
    457     def _initialize_providers(self, credentials: Credentials) -> None:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\providers\ibmq\api\clients\version.py in version(self)
     49                 * ``api-*`` (str): The versions of each individual API component
     50         """
---> 51         return self.client_version_finder.version()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\providers\ibmq\api\rest\root.py in version(self)
    102         """
    103         url = self.get_url('version')
--> 104         response = self.session.get(url)
    105 
    106         try:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in get(self, url, **kwargs)
    541 
    542         kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
--> 543         return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
    544 
    545     def options(self, url, **kwargs):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\providers\ibmq\api\session.py in request(self, method, url, bare, **kwargs)
    294                 self._modify_chained_exception_messages(ex)
    295 
--> 296             raise RequestsApiError(message, status_code) from ex
    297 
    298         return response

RequestsApiError: '403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://auth.quantum-computing.ibm.com/api/version. <!DOCTYPE html>\n<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->\n<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->\n<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->\n<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->\n<head>\n<title>Access denied | auth.quantum-computing.ibm.com used Cloudflare to restrict access</title>\n<meta charset="UTF-8" />\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />\n<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />\n<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />\n<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />\n<link rel="stylesheet" id="cf_styles-css" href="/cdn-cgi/styles/main.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />\n\n\n</head>\n<body>\n  <div id="cf-wrapper">\n    <div class="cf-alert cf-alert-error cf-cookie-error hidden" id="cookie-alert" data-translate="enable_cookies">Please enable cookies.</div>\n    <div id="cf-error-details" class="p-0">\n      <header class="mx-auto pt-10 lg:pt-6 lg:px-8 w-240 lg:w-full mb-15 antialiased">\n         <h1 class="inline-block md:block mr-2 md:mb-2 font-light text-60 md:text-3xl text-black-dark leading-tight">\n           <span data-translate="error">Error</span>\n           <span>1009</span>\n         </h1>\n         <span class="inline-block md:block heading-ray-id font-mono text-15 lg:text-sm lg:leading-relaxed">Ray ID: 6250695e3c814e6d &bull;</span>\n         <span class="inline-block md:block heading-ray-id font-mono text-15 lg:text-sm lg:leading-relaxed">2021-02-21 12:18:43 UTC</span>\n        <h2 class="text-gray-600 leading-1.3 text-3xl lg:text-2xl font-light">Access denied</h2>\n      </header>\n\n      <section class="w-240 lg:w-full mx-auto mb-8 lg:px-8">\n          <div id="what-happened-section" class="w-1/2 md:w-full">\n            <h2 class="text-3xl leading-tight font-normal mb-4 text-black-dark antialiased" data-translate="what_happened">What happened?</h2>\n            <p>The owner of this website (auth.quantum-computing.ibm.com) has banned the country or region your IP address is in (IR) from accessing this website.</p>\n            \n          </div>\n\n          \n      </section>\n\n      <div class="cf-error-footer cf-wrapper w-240 lg:w-full py-10 sm:py-4 sm:px-8 mx-auto text-center sm:text-left border-solid border-0 border-t border-gray-300">\n  <p class="text-13">\n    <span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1">Cloudflare Ray ID: <strong class="font-semibold">6250695e3c814e6d</strong></span>\n    <span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">&bull;</span>\n    <span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1"><span>Your IP</span>: 2.183.208.51</span>\n    <span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">&bull;</span>\n    <span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1"><span>Performance &amp; security by</span> <a rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing" id="brand_link" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a></span>\n    \n  </p>\n</div><!-- /.error-footer -->\n\n\n    </div><!-- /#cf-error-details -->\n  </div><!-- /#cf-wrapper -->\n\n  <script type="text/javascript">\n  window._cf_translation = {};\n  \n  \n</script>\n\n</body>\n</html>\n'```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation is in the body of the message (after some scrolling):

```
The owner of this website (auth.quantum-computing.ibm.com)
has banned the country or region your IP address is in (IR)
from accessing this website.
```

Comment: thanks I used a vpn to fix it